# Tiktok api error 10006. How to make my tiktok app "live in production" how to draft term of use

Tags: privacy, tiktok, tiktok-api

[Tiktok api error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/modZz.png)

My tiktok app is staging. When I login with tiktok api, it always returns this error "redirect_uri" is incorrect. I have double checked that the redirect_uri is correct. Do you know why?

Is it because the app is in staging but not live in production?

I submit my app for reviewing but not approved. The review comment is that the term of use and privacy are not complying with Tiktok developer term of service.

I have rewritten the term of use and privacy for many times but don't know to make it comply with tiktok's policy.

Do you have good template or know how to write term of use and privacy complying tiktok's term of use?

Answer (score 1):

If your app is in staging then it will not work. Staging means you are setting your application up with tiktok, and preparing to submit for review.

After you submit for review, it will take 1-3 days for TikTok to approve/disapprove your application. If approved, you will see "Live in Production"

Essentially, TikTok just hasn't approved your redirect URI yet.

**Note**: Tiktok will not redirect to localhost, so use something like [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) and include that URI in your redirect URIs to be able to test